# Select max from subquery group by

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select max of subquery. I tried the following  SELECT MAX(SELECT COUNT(lid) AS count FROM Lessons GROUP BY day) , but it obviously failed. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(myCount) FROM (SELECT COUNT(lid) AS myCount FROM Lessons GROUP BY day) AS sub Query
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just

```
SELECT COUNT(lid) AS count 
FROM Lessons 
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY count desc
limit 1
```